# Unidentified Errors.Please notify... error instead of my simple forms.ValidationError

Tags: python, django, django-forms

OK, trying to add a clean method to a ModelForm in Django.  I'm adding a simple raise statement just to see if it works, and instead of my message, I get "Unidentified Errors.  Please notify..."

Here's my (simple) test:

```
class ConfigurationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        typeid = cleaned_data.get("typeid")
        value = cleaned_data.get("value")  

        if value and typeid:
            raise forms.ValidationError("this is the error")
```

I couldn't even find a reference to "Unidentified Errors" anywhere in the django code base.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you haven't added a method. Look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: sorry - edited my code to reflect it.

Comment: pasty:  Yeah, I've looked there... that's where my code effectively came from.  It seems so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your clean method returning the cleaned_data? If you look at the docs here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

you'll notice you have to make sure to return self.cleaned_data. Furthermore, don't raise validation errors; instead delete the invalid field from the data (again, as you have to return it)

So:

```
def clean(self):
    typeid = cleaned_data.get("typeid", False)
    value = cleaned_data.get("value", False)  
    if value and typeid:
         self._errors["typeid"] = self.error_class(["Some error has happened"])
         del(self.cleaned_data['typeid'])   
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: Turns out I was missing something somewhere else... The template to be exact (I wasn't catching this specific error with non_field_errors).  Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use clean model methond intensively.

You should search for your errors on NON_FIELD_ERRORS:

On template:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
   <ul>
      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
       <li> {{error}} </li>
      {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endif %}
```

On code:

```
form._errors.[NON_FIELD_ERRORS]
```

[Here you can learn about how to move business rules from forms to model](http://beutil.blogspot.com/2011/10/django-moving-business-rules-from-views.html).